# Echo double quotes inside double quotes issue

Tags: php, escaping, echo

How is that possible to use double quotes inside PHP echo double quotes? The class `"problem"` is a problem.

```
 echo " new function('<span class="problem"></span>');";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this..

```
echo "new function('<span class=\"problem\"></span>');";
```

i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
echo <<<END
All the text u wanna echo
u can use double and single quotes
END;
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately.